# Cloudkit app with same codebase, macOS uses development database, iOS uses production

Tags: cloudkit, swift-data, xcode-cloud

I have this situation where I released an app with the same code base for iOS and macOS.
I use Xcode-cloud for the processing of the apps and let Xcode and Xcode-cloud handle all my signing.

However, the resulting apps, both retrieved from the App Stores, cannot share data together via Cloudkit as the iOS version is using the correct production version and the macOS version is using the wrong development version of the application.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, for me the fix was that CloudKit.framework has to be included in the app target's "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section, with "Do Not Embed" option and only for macOS.

I found it from here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717838

Comment: Thanks @Mark! And welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried this but it didn't work for me. :-(